# SQLException.getErrorCode and SQLCODE

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle procedure, that uses PL/SQL `SQLCODE` function in EXCEPTION section. Now I need to translate that procedure in Java. I found `SQLException.getErrorCode` function. Are results of `SQLCODE` and `SQLException.getErrorCode` the same? Is there right way to get result of `SQLCODE` function in Java?

Comment: According to the javadocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode()

    `Retrieves the vendor-specific exception code for this SQLException object.`

Try it and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent.

`SQLException.getErrorCode()`: Retrieves the vendor-specific exception code. (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/jsr169/java/sql/SQLException.html))
`SQLCODE` : In an exception handler, the `SQLCODE` function returns the numeric code of the exception being handled. (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sqlcode_function.htm))

Suppose if you have a query in which you have specified wrong table name. Then you will get `942` instead of `ORA-00942`, because `getErrorCode()` returns `int`.